# my program is not getting executed even after installing flask_wtf through virtual environment

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField

app=Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY']='mysecretkey'
class InfoForm(FlaskForm):
    breed = StringField("What Breed are you?")
    submit =SubmitField('submit')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index0():
    breed=False
    form = InfoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       breed= form.breed.data
       form.breed.data =''
    return render_template('index0.html,form=form,breed=breed')

    if __name__  == '__name__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

THIS IS MY PYTHON FILE CODE.

```
  <p>
    {% if breed %}
    The breed you entered is {{breed}}
    update in the form below:
    {% else %}
    Please enter your breed:
    {% endif %}
 </p>

 <form  method="post">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}
      {{form.breed.label}} {{form.breed()}}
      {{form.submit()}}

 </form>
```

THIS IS MY HTML CODE

```
base) Shreyanks-MacBook-Air:Downloads shreyankiyengar$ source activate myflaskenv
(myflaskenv) Shreyanks-MacBook-Air:Downloads shreyankiyengar$ pip install flask_wtf
Requirement already satisfied: flask_wtf in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask_wtf) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask_wtf) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask_wtf) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask->flask_wtf) 
(2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask->flask_wtf) 
(7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask->flask_wtf) 
(1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in 
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/myflaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from WTForms- 
>flask_wtf) (1.1.1)
(myflaskenv) Shreyanks-MacBook-Air:Downloads shreyankiyengar$ python implectureudemy.py
(myflaskenv) Shreyanks-MacBook-Air:Downloads shreyankiyengar$
```

This is my terminal as u can see, even after using my virtual environment and trying to run flask_wt(after installing it through pip) its not getting executed..This is the problem that i am facing. Can someone pls help.

Comment: don't you get error message when you start it in console/terminal ? I don't see any problem in your question - it seems all works correctly.

Comment: You have wrong indentation - line `if __name__  == '__name__':` is inside `index0` so it never runs your code. And this is all your problem

Comment: other problems - it has to be string `"__main__"` in `if __name__  == '__main__':`. And you have closing `'` in wrong place in line `render_template('index0.html', form=form, breed=breed)` - it has to be after `index0.html`, not after `breed=breed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three mistakes in code:

1. you have wrong indentation in line with `if __name__  == '__name__':` and it is inside `index0()` - so it never runs it and it never starts your application.
2. it has to be string `"__main__"` instead of `"__name__"`
3. you have closing `'` in wrong place in `render_template('index0.html', form=form, breed=breed)` - it has to be after `index0.html`, not after `breed=breed`

---

I did't run it to see if there are other problems.

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField


app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'


class InfoForm(FlaskForm):
    breed = StringField("What Breed are you?")
    submit = SubmitField('submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index0():
    breed = False
    form = InfoForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
       breed = form.breed.data
       form.breed.data = ''

    return render_template('index0.html', form=form, breed=breed)


if __name__  == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```